# Lower bound on mean minimum distance($l_{\infty}$) between a test random vector $X'$ and vectors $X_1, \dots X_N$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose we draw a independent random vector $X'$ uniformly from a unit hypercube, $[0, 1]^d$. Given similarly drawn vectors $X_1 \dots X_n$ we can define the following quantity

$\rho_{\infty}(d, n):= \mathbb{E}_{X', \mathbf{X}} \left[ min_{i \in [1, n]}|X' - X_i|_{\infty}   \right]$

Here $l_{\infty}$ norm is used. I have been trying to show the following lower bound to $\rho_{\infty}$ without success.

$\ln \rho_{\infty}(d, n) \geq \ln \frac{d}{2(d+1)} - \frac{\ln n}{d}$

Does anyone have a hint or simple heuristic to prove this lower bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\rho:=\rho_{\infty}(d,n)$ and $m:=\min_{1\le i\le n}\|X'-X_i\|_\infty$. We want to show that
$$\rho\overset{\text{(?)}}\ge\frac d{2(d+1)}\,n^{-1/d}.\tag1$$

For $I:=[0,1]$, we have
$$\rho=\int_I dt\,P(m>t)$$
and, for $t\in I$,
\begin{align}P(m>t)&=\int_{I^d}P(X'\in dx)P(\min_{1\le i\le n}\|x-X_i\|_\infty>t) \\
&=\int_{I^d}P(X'\in dx)P(\|x-X_1\|_\infty>t)^n \\
&\ge\int_{I^d}P(X'\in dx)(1-(2t)^d)^n=(1-(2t)^d)^n. 
\end{align}
So,
$$\rho\ge\int_I dt\,(1-(2t)^d)^n\ge\int_0^{n^{-1/d}/2} dt\,(1-n(2t)^d)
=\frac d{2(d+1)}\,n^{-1/d},$$
so that (1) follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask whether the tricks/methods used here are rather standard? Is this result well known ?

Comment: @vishmay : As you can see, the methods here are pretty straightforward. I had not known this before your post. How did you come up with this lower bound?

Comment: Thank you. This bound was used for an analysis in a high dimensional stats book. I don't quite see how you got the integral form for $P(m > t)$, it seems that one of the factors in the integrand is $P(m > t)$? Apologies I am new to probability.  I haven't seen the notation $P(X' \in dx)$

Comment: @vishmay : Can you tell us in what particular book you saw this bound? As for the integral form for $P(m>t)$, here it is just a short way to write $P(m>t)$ as an $(n+1)d$-fold integral over $(I^d)^{n+1}$. You can also say that this integral representation of $P(m>t)$ is obtained by the conditioning on $X'$. The integrand is -- not $P(m>t)$ -- but, in a sense, the conditional probability $P(m>t|X'=x)$, and the integral representation can be considered an instance of the total probability formula for an uncountable family of cases/hypotheses.

Comment: Previous comment continued: As for $P(X'\in dx)$, it is a standard notation for $\mu(dx)$, where $\mu$ is the probability **measure** that is the probability distribution of $X'$; in this particular case, you can also write $dx$ in place of $P(X'\in dx)$. It appears that you can benefit from taking a course on probability **based on measure theory**.

Comment: @Iosis Pinelis Thank you so much. That makes it very clear for me. The book I found this in is "High dimensional Statistics: A non-asymptotic viewpoint, Martin J Wainwright" (https://www.amazon.com/High-Dimensional-Statistics-Non-Asymptotic-Statistical-Probabilistic/dp/1108498027).The lower bound is in page 8, eq (1.14). I am currently reading Folland (Real Analysis) on measure theory but has only got to 2 chapters for now. Thank you for your advice.